# ios rss parse html content inside <content> tag

Tags: ios, xml-parsing, rss

Am trying to parse a RSS feed using NSXMLPARSER. Am getting the title, images, pubDate every thing but the problem is with content tag. Here content tag have html content coming from rss. So how can i get all the data inside content tag along with html. My Data is below.

```
    <content><p>(مستعمل )<br />
•مرسيدس بانورما<br />
•   موديل 2008<br />
•   محرك 6 سلندر 3.5 لتر<br />
•   جيراتوماتيك<br />
•   العداد 107.000كلم<br />
•   مقاعد جلد جملي<br />
•   وسائد هوائية<br />
•   جنوط amg<br />
•   اللون لؤلؤي<br />
السياره فل كامل &#8211; سقف بانورما &#8211; رؤيه ليله &#8211; نافيشين سستم gps &#8211; شاشات خلفيه جنوط amg 20 &#8211; السياره نظيفه وغاية المستخدم تم تعديل سعر السياره 159الف ريال قابل للتفاوض في حدود المعقول<br />
كما يتوفر لدينا جميع انواع السيارات جديده ومستعمله ويوجد لدينا تاجير منتهي بالتمليك<br />
معرض السفير الشرقي للسيارات الدمام الخضريه<br />
طريق الجبيل الظهران السريع<br />
سيارات جديده &#8211; مستعمله &#8211; خدمات المرور<br />
للتواصل 0583188870&#8211;0556802016<br />
زورو معرضنا<br />
السفير سفيرك لاختيار سيارتك &#8230;.</p>
</content>
```

And am using below code to get the content.

```
-(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSLog(@"Before: %@",string);


    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) string;

}
```

Am not getting any thing from this content tag others like title, image and date doesn't have html so am getting without any problem. So what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foundCharacter can be called multiple times, so you have to check for the tag:

The tag you want to get the content is the `<p>` tag not the `<content>` tag because NSXMLParser thinks that `<p>` is part of the xml stracture.

You should generate all HTML inside `<![CDATA[<html> ... </html> ]]` and then put it in the content tag. Otherwise the parser wont get it. For CDATA you can use this delegate method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Comment: the <p> tag is coming from database itself, so may be some times this <p> tag will not come. So my main tag is <content> tag which will return some content with <p>  or without <p>.

Comment: Edited my answer. Thats the only way to do it without issues.

Comment: Can you tell me for CDATA how to parse, this below method not returning content inside CDATA also. -(void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string 
{
    NSLog(@"Before: %@",string);


    currentNodeContent = (NSMutableString *) string;

}

Comment: The point of CDATA is that anything within it is not treated as part of the XML document. So if you have tags in CDATA the parser will ignore them. You just have to look for the elementName "content". Edited my answer with another delegate method you can call.

Comment: hello NIkos can you tell me how to get multiple CDATA elements from you answer like if i have <content> and <description> both and how to find which element is coming from - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock
{
    NSString *someString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:CDATABlock encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
} this method

Comment: declare a `NSString` called `elementName`. Where you read elements pass the `elementName` to that `NSString`. In `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCDATA:(NSData *)CDATABlock` just do a check `if (elementName isEqualTo:@"content")` and do what you want :-)